# Performance and weirness of HashMap

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

Nested HashMap performance.

HashMap I have the following:

`HashMap <String, HashMap <String, HashMap <String,String>>> table = new HashMap <String,     HashMap <String, HashMap <String, String> >>();`

this is right?

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you have any specific problems?  Doesn't it compile?  And you might want to add the tag Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HashMap <String, HashMap <String, HashMap <String,String>>> table1 = new HashMap <String, HashMap <String, HashMap <String, String> >>();
```

↑ perfectly fine.

In terms of nesting the HashMaps, a better option might be to concatenate the keys and use a non-nested HashMap if you're typically interested in the end values and not the intermediate maps.

...in other words, define a `Triple` class with three strings, and define a hashcode and equals method, etc. Then use:

```
HashMap<Triple,String> table2 = new HashMap<Triple,String>();
```

...again, this assumes that your lookup operation takes three strings and returns one value.

---

To do lookups on `table1`, you need to do:

```
String val = table1.get(key1).get(key2).get(key3);
```

To do lookups on `table2`, you need to do:

```
Triple keyt = new Triple(key1, key2, key3);
String val = table2.get(keyt);
```

(...FWIW, doing inserts on `table2` is must easier).

Comment: Can you do a workbench to test contains performance to prove your idea? Just assume this map is used for readonly.

Comment: please tell me ¿how i can get the values?

Comment: In nested HashMap I do HashMap.get(key).get(key1).etc ... for values

can you tell me how can obtain them from a Triple?

Answer (score 0):

Hash containers are designed for efficiency(O(1)), so performance is no problem here. I think memory consume will be problem, as many buckets are needed in your HashMaps.

In other hand, if the sizes of your HashMaps are not huge, it's OK.